# Is the following generalization of Jensen's inequality known?

Tags: probability, convex-analysis

I believe the following statement is true, but I can't find a proof anywhere. Does someone know if there is a reference or if it has a name?

> Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be convex. Let $X$ be a random variable so that $f(X)$ is defined.  Let $\gamma \in [0,1]$. If $\mathbb{E}[X]=0$, then $\mathbb{E}[f(\gamma X)] \leq \mathbb{E}[f(X)]$.

Setting $\gamma=0$ is simply Jensen's inequality.

Comment: @T.Bongers  The case $\gamma=0$ is true and it is Jensen's Inequality: $$\mathbb{E}\big[f(0\cdot X)\big]=f(0)=f\big(\mathbb{E}[X]\big)\leq \mathbb{E}\big[f(X)\big]\,.$$  Perhaps, you didn't see the requirement that $\mathbb{E}[X]=0$ (I made that mistake too).

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Comment: See Rudin RCA Chapter 3. Perhaps that would help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The result is a corollary of Jensen's inequality. If $\gamma\in[0,1]$ then by convexity
$$f(\gamma X)=f(\gamma X + (1-\gamma)0)\le
\gamma f(X)+(1-\gamma)f(0).$$
Taking expectations,
$$
{\mathbb E}[f(\gamma X)]\le \gamma {\mathbb E}[f(X)]+(1-\gamma) f(0).
$$
But $f(0)=f({\mathbb E}[X])$, and by Jensen this last is at most ${\mathbb E}[f(X)]$. Finally $1-\gamma\ge0$, so $$(1-\gamma)f(0)\le(1-\gamma){\mathbb E}[f(X)],$$
and the result is proved. (So the result is both a generalization and a corollary of Jensen...)

Comment: In other words, the two are equivalent.

Comment: I was gonna say that. In other words, $\lambda\mapsto\Bbb E[\lambda X]$ is convex.